# Edit liferay dockbar jsp page error

Tags: jsp, liferay-6

I want to customize liferay dockbar view.jsp page and want to add a text(Project Version) which is coming from a bean java file. But the problem is that I got an error when I want to initialize the java class. I am very new to liferay, also dont know whether it is possible to create a external class object in liferay jsp page or not. Here is my code::

```
        <%@page import="net.simplyfiIT.bean.UserManagementBean"%>

        <%
        String version;     
        UserManagementBean bean=new UserManagementBean();
        version=bean.getVersion();
        %>
```

Error message:

```
          Only a type can be imported. net.simplyfiIT.bean.UserManagementBean resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: 342 in the jsp file: /html/portlet/dockbar/view.jsp
 UserManagementBean cannot be resolved to a type
 339:               
 340:               <%
341:                String version;
342:                UserManagementBean bean=new UserManagementBean();
 343:               version=bean.getVersion();
 344:                   
  345: 


  Stacktrace:
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:331)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:469)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:73)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:593)
```

Note: Bean class is compiled in tomcat directories.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use:

```
<jsp:useBean id="someID" class="net.simplyfiIT.bean.UserManagementBean">
```

instead of

```
<%@page import="net.simplyfiIT.bean.UserManagementBean"%>
```

The Bean should be placed in the classpath.

(I'm a noob myself)